# plot multiple cumulative percentage graph by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, cdf, ecdf, cumulative-frequency

I have data looks like:

```
zip   ID    count
230   B      12
230   A      10
230   C       9
230   D       5
270   C      10
270   A       9
270   B       8
290   C       9
290   A       8
290   B       6
```

`zip` and `ID` are factor and `count` is numeric. ID is uniquely associated with count. Within each level of zip, count is in desc order.

How can I create cumulative percentage graphs by each level of `zip` for `count` (in this case, I need 3 graphs in one window) and at the same time ticking the x-axis using `ID`? Also, the x-axis will keep the desc order or count (which means, the largest percentage goes first).

So far I read that ggplot2 has ecdf built-in, but I don't know how to generate multiple graphs there. I tried

```
p<-qplot(dat,stat='ecdf',geom='count')+facet_wrap(~zip,ncol=10)
```

But it didn't work at all.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=count) )+stat_ecdf()+facet_wrap(~zip,ncol=10)
```

(Although the ncol argument seems to get ignored.)

Comment: I tried this, but the largest percentage count didn't go first :-(

Comment: The order of plots is determined by the alpha sorting value of the 'zip' levels. (I couldn't figure out which one had the "highest cumulative percentage" because they each have a cumulative percentage of 100%.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out what I wanted is ccdf.